# Basic code help for chrome console

Tags: javascript

I understand this is extremely basic but I have almost no coding experience and have yet to find why this function always return undefined please help.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x,y;
    y = document.getElementById("nent_nonce");
    z = document.getElementById("next_server_seed_hash");
}
</script>
```

the new code i used i took out the script because it kept giving me and unexpected token < which i intend to fix later

```
function x() {
return [ $('#next_nonce').html(), $('#next_server_seed_hash').html() ]
}
```

this is what gave me the undefined although trying either document.getelementbyid worked

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript functions return `undefined` unless you explicitly `return` something. Consider:

```
function x() {
  5;
}
```

When you call `x()` you get `undefined`.

Instead:

```
function x() {
  return 5;
}
```

If you don't have a good JavaScript reference you will not get very far without one. The good news is [Mozilla has fantastic documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/bm/docs/Web/JavaScript) to get you started.

One solution to returning two elements is to use an array, as in:

```
function x() {
  return [
    $('#next_nonce').html(),
    $('#next_server_seed_hash').html()
  ];
}
```

Or you can return a JavaScript object:

```
function x() {
  return {
    next_nonce: $('#next_nonce').html(),
    next_server_seed_hash: $('#next_server_seed_hash').html()
  };
}
```

Where using `html()` implies these are standard HTML elements that have content within them, like `<div>` or `<p>`. If these are form elements you should use `val()` to get the `value="..."` property within the tag.

Comment: Well thank you for the link i will be sure to check it out. And sorry to bother but i have a quick follow up question if you don't mind. Could i use the document.getelementbyid as my return? So that it would return the value of that element.

Comment: That's the idea. Just `return` whatever you want and you'll get that back from your function. As a note, you might want to look at tools like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) which can dramatically reduce how much JavaScript code you need to write. In this case your code boils down to `return [ $('#nent_nonce').html(), $('#next_server_seed_hash').html() ]` if you're looking to return two values at once.

Comment: Try running the `getElementById` code in isolation to make sure you're getting the right data first. Then integrate it. As always, check for errors in your JavaScript console.

Comment: Probably an error on me but i checked the code found a slight typo fixed that and still got undefined

Comment: Can you edit your question to show your updated code? It's worth adding it at the end to contrast with the original, keep both versions.

Comment: What kind of elements are these? Is jQuery loaded now?

Comment: I'm sorry in advance i feel like i'm wasting a lot of your time because of how little i know on this but I actually don't even know what type they are or how to find out.

Comment: With jQuery you can test: `$('#next_nonce')` will give you the HTML element and you can try different things on it. This presumes jQuery is loaded. Many sites have it by default, but yours may not. One tool to help is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) where you can save various attempts and iterate more systematically. That works in pretty much any browser on any device.

Comment: Ok well thank you so, so much. I'm going to go and read the Mozilla document and try to get jQuery to work if not i will return to this.